# Can not change the text using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I made a small project where i try to change the name from edit text using share preference.Here is my code

**SharePreferenceOwnActivity.java**

```
public class SharePreferenceOwnActivity extends Activity {


    Button b1;
    TextView t1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        LoadPreferences();




        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(SharePreferenceOwnActivity.this, SharepreferenceActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
    private void LoadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
        t1.setText(strSavedMem1);

    }
}
```

**SharepreferenceActivity.java**

```
public class SharepreferenceActivity extends Activity {


    EditText e1;
    Button b2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);


        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);


        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                SavePreferences("MEM1", e1.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(SharepreferenceActivity.this, SharePreferenceOwnActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Here the edit text doesnot change the textview. :( why? I did not get the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem in following statement.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**As per Google Doc**

> The above Retrieves a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity

**So the Error you have done is**

you are setting preference in Preference Object which is private to
 `SharepreferenceActivity`

And

you are trying to read from Preference Object which is private to `SharePreferenceOwnActivity`

So solution is

Replace

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

By

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                                      Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In Both Activities.

Answer (score 1):

call your `LoadPreferences()` method  on onResume() on SharePreferenceOwnActivity Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Call here
       LoadPreferences();
    }
```

and change SavePreferences and LoadPreferences methods as:

In SharepreferenceActivity Activity :

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSHaredPreferences("aapname",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
    }
}
```

In SharePreferenceOwnActivity Activity:

```
private void LoadPreferences() {
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("aapname",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.getString("MEM1", "");
t1.setText(strSavedMem1);
}
```

Comment: SharePreferenceOwnActivity Activity

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha : make sure you are getting value from SharedPreferences ?

Comment: do i need to use SharedPreferences  method in both activity?

Comment: what about this line ,it shows error in settngs `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();`

Comment: ya.it does not require  onResume().just chane the `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);` mode.

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha : plz delete all all un usefull comments from your side form this chat

Answer (score 1):

The two preferences you are obtaining are not visible from one Activity to the other. Instead of

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

use

```
getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can change `"myPreferences"` to whatever you like. You should define it as a static String somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
t1.setText(strSavedMem1);
```

Try to declare SharedPreferences  this way in both activities.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
```

And when you call startActivity() in both classes. Try to call

```
finish();
```

in both classes